# Item inside the flexbox doesn't cover the whole width, even when set to 100%

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to center some elements so that they visually align.

The top div has some strange space on the right, and it's making all the content inside that div, pushed over and not truly centered. The bottom div (colored circles) are truly center aligned.

[image]

Interestingly:
It's not padding, and it's not margin.

Using Chrome inspect tools, I can see that there's some purple lined area, which apparently means the content in the top div is not taking up all of the available space:

[image]

After checking and unchecking styles in the inspector, I can't seem to get that purple area to disappear.

How can I make the content in the div take up all of the available space?

As a hack, I could just temporarily add 15px of margin to the circles, but it still looks somewhat off on mobile, so I'm seeking the real answer.

Where is that purple lined are coming from?

Here's the HTML:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="container navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light mt-3" style="padding:15px;background-color:blue;">

  <div class="row w-100 align-items-center">

    <div class="col-6 col-sm order-1 order-sm-1">
      <h1 class="me-auto">
        <a href="/" class="text-body" style="text-decoration: none;">Some Title</a>
      </h1>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-sm order-3 order-sm-2 text-center      mt-3 mt-sm-0  " style="background-color: green;">
      <form class="w-100 mx-auto" action="/askgpt" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="blah" autocomplete="off">
        <input autocomplete="off" type="hidden" name="blah" id="blah">
        <input type="text" name="prompt" id="prompt" value="" class="form-control form-control-lg mb-2 w-100" placeholder="move the start of this session 10m forward">
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-sm order-2 order-sm-3 text-end">
      <div class="nav-item dropdown ms-0" style="max-height: 40px;">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 35px;">menu</i>  </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink" style="font-size:30px;">

          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/home">Week view</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/leaderboard">Leaderboard</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/purchase">Buy now</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>

          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/entries">Edit times</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" id="lightdark">Dark ☽</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: That looks to me like the way that chrome displays flex layout and grid layout spacing, but it's hard to say with no style information - though I'm pretty sure I see a `display: flex` in the screen pic.  Pictures of words are not a good substitute for words.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @StephenP I've edited the question to include the source code.

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you @gre_gor, that was exactly it. Can you post that and I'll mark it as the answer? Or as soon as stackoverflow gets out of my way I'll do it.

Comment: Right, I think I edited the title and submitted it for review to get it reopened. What a pain. I find that I'm constantly frustrated by stackoverflow getting in my way, not letting me edit, people editing the question incorrectly etc. e.g. The person who closed this clearly didn't read or understand the question, and marked it as a duplicate incorrectly.

Comment: @gre_gor It's been reopened! If you'd like to leave your comment as the answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The margin is on the child of the element that you are looking at.
The Bootstrap's `.row` negative gutter margin is shifting it to the left and making space on the right, while still being 100% width.

[image: margin]

Remove that margin, by adding `m-0` class to that `div`.